# Is it possible to have a 3 by 3 positive definite matrix whose s-sparse solutions have the same nonzero elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Give a $3 \times 3$ positive definite matrix $A$ as the following:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \epsilon & \zeta \\
\epsilon & \beta & \eta \\ 
\zeta & \eta & \gamma
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and a vector $\mathbf{b}=[b_1, b_2, b_3]^{\top}$.

A vector $\mathbf{x}_s \in \mathbb{R}^s$ is called an $s$-sparse solution when $x_i\neq 0$ for $i \in J \subset \{1,2,3\}$ where cardinality of $J$ is $s<3$. Let $A_J \in \mathbb{R}^{s \times s}$ be a principal submatrix of $A$ where we pick elements of $A$ whose rows and columns are in $J$. Also, $\mathbf{b}_J \in \mathbb{R}^s$ is obtained by maintaining all entries that are in $J$.

Is it possible to have a $3 \times 3$ positive definite matrix whose $s$-sparse solutions have the same nonzero elements, i.e., $A_J\mathbf{x}_s=\mathbf{b}_J$?

**My try:**

There does not exists such an $\mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ solution because if it existed we would have the following ones:

$\mathbf{x}_1=x , J=\{1\}$
$\mathbf{x}_1=x, J=\{2\}$
$\mathbf{x}_1=, J=\{3\}$

Plugging in $A_J\mathbf{x}_s=\mathbf{b}_J$, the above means the following:

$b_1=(\alpha+ \epsilon+ \zeta)x$, $b_2=(\epsilon + \beta + \eta)x$, $b_3=(\zeta+ \eta+ \gamma)x$
which implies the sum of each column should have a specific value. Therefore, it violates the positive definiteness of $A$.

When $s=2$ we have the following:

$\mathbf{x}_2=[x,x]^{\top} , J=\{1,2\}$
$\mathbf{x}_2=[x,x]^{\top}, J=\{1,3\}$
$\mathbf{x}_2=[x,x]^{\top}, J=\{2,3\}$

Plugging in $A_J\mathbf{x}_s=\mathbf{b}_J$, the above means the following:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \epsilon \\
\epsilon & \beta \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \zeta\\
\zeta& \gamma 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
b_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta & \eta\\
\eta& \gamma\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_2\\
b_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$.

I do not know how to proceed?